# Record multiple audio streams simultaneously using webRTC (with different settings)

Tags: audio, webrtc, audio-recording, recording, simultaneous

User is using one microphone, I am capable of recording him using webRTC with some audio enhancements (AEC, AGC, NS, etc.) turned on/off.

But is it possible to record him at least "doubly" (simultaneously):
- one recording using webRTC with AEC turned on
- second recording using webRTC with AEC turned off